# Multiple python files in AWS Lambda artifact

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I am trying to use simple settings on an aws lambda function, and I have the following file directory:

artifact.zip

- app.py (include lambda_handler())
- settings.py
- settings_dev.py
- other imports

My issue is that the lambda file does not seem to recognize the settings_dev.py (or settings.py) file when I try it.

When I call it locally, I am able to load settings fine. However, when I run this within a lambda, and print out what settings is by `print(settings.__dict__)` , I get an empty dictionary:

```
In __init__:
# print the simple settings
print(f"Simple settings: {os.environ['SIMPLE_SETTINGS']}")

- Simple settings: settings_dev

print(f"File structure: {os.listdir('.')}")

- File structure: ['googleapiclient', .... 'settings_dev.py',  'settings.py',  'app.py',]

settings = LazySettings() # Returns an empty list, though calling this locally works fine. 

print(settings.__dict__)

{'_settings_list': ['settings_dev'], '_initialized': False, '_dict': {}, '_dynamic_reader': None, 'strategies': (<class 'simple_settings.strategies.python.SettingsLoadStrategyPython'>, 


statsd.host = settings.STATSD_HOST
statsd.port = settings.STATSD_PORT


<class 'simple_settings.strategies.cfg.SettingsLoadStrategyCfg'>, <class 'simple_settings.strategies.json_file.SettingsLoadStrategyJson'>, <class 'simple_settings.strategies.environ.SettingsLoadStrategyEnviron'>, <class 'simple_settings.strategies.yaml_file.SettingsLoadStrategyYaml'>)}

    raise RuntimeError('Invalid settings file [{}]'.format(settings_file))ileneule
```

Comment: Are you using SAM, CDK or manually uploading it to the console? Can you share how do you specify the handler?